Excel - Insert object VBA returning blank object & corrupt excel
A macro is running throughout quite a large workbook that, where triggered, prompts the user to insert an object within the selected cell in a specific size.
We are having intermittent issues where the inserted object (generally PDF) will appear as a white box and corrupt the excel workbook to the point where it cannot be saved without the objects being deleted. This issue has been occurring more frequently in the last fortnight.
Code below:
Sub InsertPackageObject()
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String 

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            filePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub ' User canceled
        End If
    End With  

    fileName = Mid(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "") + 1)  

    Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(fileName:=filePath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True)

    obj.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    obj.Width = 72
    obj.Height = 62

End Sub

I have tried many variations of the macro to try fix the issue. The macro has been copied to a clean workbook and it doesnt work, I have updated ActiveX settings in the Trust Centre, and I have tried to run it on 3 different computers with varying Microsoft 365 licenses; all to no avail.
Hope the insert object VBA works in the same way as Insert > Object > Package does without the manual click-through
Would love any feedback on how to get this up and running again?

What is the idea of InStrRev(filePath, "")? It will always return the length of filePath, therefore fileName is blank.

fileName is the name of a parameter to the OLEObjects.Add method so not a good choice for a user variable.
